# Random Number Generating

Tags: javascript, random

I try to generate `number of year` randomly.

But I can't get the result what I expected.

This is my sample code.

```js
function getNumber(start, end) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * end) + start;
}

function generate(n){
  var result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    let YEAR = getNumber(1900,2018);
    result.push(YEAR);
  }
  /* I want to see the number 1900 ~ 2018 */
  console.log(result);
}
generate(10);
```

I want to get the number between 1900 and 2018 but I can't.

How can I get the number what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding to `start` a number which can be up to `end` (minus one). What you need it is to be up to `end-start`.

Just change

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * end) + start;
```

to

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end-start)) + start;
```

Comment: I missed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, just make it

```
Math.random() * (end-start)
```

instead of

```
Math.random() * end
```

**Demo**

```js
function getNumber(start, end) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end-start)) + start;
}

function generate(n){
  var result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
    let YEAR = getNumber(1900,2018);
    result.push(YEAR);
  }
  /* I want to see the number 1900 ~ 2018 */
  console.log(result);
}
generate(10);
```